# Can I write bytes into audio output using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, audio

There are examples on Qt website regarding using audio API, but frankly I don't really understand them at all.

What I was imagining is writing array of values (bytes, integers...) into some audio buffer and have the sound card "play" them (actually DAC them).

Pseudocode:

```
// Square wave?
const int values[] = {255,255,255,255, 0,0,0,0, 255,255,255,255 ...};
// Create output that will buffer the bytes and put them on digi to analog converter
RawAudioOutput output(BIT_RATE_CONSTANT, ... some other parameters ...);
output.start();
output.writeBytes(values, sizeof(values));
```

Can I accomplish something like that? How would I go about it? I know I can model square wave in Audacity (doesn't sound nice), so I guess it's possible. How?

Answer (score 2):

In Qt, if you want to write an array of values into an audio buffer, the class for that is [QAudioOutput](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiooutput.html). The format of the array of values can vary, the [PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) format should be supported by all platforms.

Qt ships with [an example that demonstrates the usage of QAudioOutput](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimedia-audiooutput-example.html), have a look at that. In the example, the `Generator::generateData()` function creates the array of values that are then later sent to the audio device.

Of course playing audio from an array of values is quite low-level. With [QMediaPlayer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html), Qt also provides a high-level class to play sound files (.wav, .mp3), video files and even streams.